# multiple contact picker with search option

Tags: android, contacts

Am developing an application which require multiple contact picker with search option.

I tried http://sachindotg.blogspot.in/2013/11/android-simple-multi-contacts-picker.html
tutorial but it is not working.

```
public class Display extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

ArrayList<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> id1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> tempArrayList;
ArrayList<String> tempArrayList1;
MyAdapter ma ;
Button select;
UserSessionManager session;
StringBuilder checkedcontacts;
String email,name;
EditText inputSearch;
int isScheduled=0;
ListView lv;
public JSONParser jsonParser;
LoginActivity  LActivity;
ContentResolver cr1;
private static String CALL_URL = "http://ec2-50-112-186-213.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/outbound_dialer/save_recording.php";
private static String SCHEDULE_URL = "http://ec2-50-112-186-213.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/outbound_dialer/store_recording.php";
private static String URL="h";
/********* for date time picker dialoge***********/

Button ShowDTPicker;
Button ShowDatePicker;
Button ShowTimePicker;
Button Set;
Button ReSet;
Button Cancel;
DatePicker DPic;
TimePicker TPic;

private ViewSwitcher switcher;
static final int DATE_TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;
Dialog dialog;
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a");
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    LActivity =new LoginActivity(); 
    ShowDTPicker = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button2));
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int textlength = arg0.length();
             tempArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
             tempArrayList1=new ArrayList<String>();
               for(String c: name1){
                  if (textlength <= c.length()) {
                     if (c.toLowerCase().contains(arg0.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        tempArrayList.add(c);
                        int loc=name1.indexOf(c);
                        tempArrayList1.add(phno1.get(loc));

                     }
                  }
               }

               Log.d("",""+tempArrayList);

                ma = new MyAdapter(tempArrayList,tempArrayList1);
                lv.setAdapter(ma);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());  // for session
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
           "User Login Status: " + session.isUserLoggedIn(), 
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 // Check user login
    // If User is not logged in , This will redirect user to LoginActivity.
    if(session.checkLogin())
        finish();
 // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

    // get name
     name = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_NAME);

    // get email
     email = user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);

    getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
    cr1=this.getContentResolver();
  //  lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        if(tempArrayList==null){
            ma = new MyAdapter(name1,phno1);
            lv.setAdapter(ma);
        }
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        // adding
       select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                 checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();

            for(int i = 0; i < phno1.size(); i++)  //name1

                {
                if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                {   
                     //checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());   //name1
                     //checkedcontacts.append(":");
                     checkedcontacts.append(phno1.get(i).toString());   //name1
                     checkedcontacts.append(",");


                }
                else
                {

                }


            }

            Toast.makeText(Display.this, checkedcontacts,1000).show();
                callNumberAndFinish(checkedcontacts);

        }


    });


    /******************************************date and time picker*******************/
      dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.datetimepicker);
        switcher = (ViewSwitcher) dialog.findViewById(R.id.DateTimePickerVS);
        DPic = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.DatePicker);
        TPic = (TimePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TimePicker);

        ShowDatePicker = ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.SwitchToDate));
        ShowDatePicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switcher.showPrevious();
                ShowDatePicker.setEnabled(false);
                ShowTimePicker.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
        ShowTimePicker = ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.SwitchToTime));
        ShowTimePicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switcher.showNext();
                ShowDatePicker.setEnabled(true);
                ShowTimePicker.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        Set = ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.SetDateTime));
        Set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                c.set(DPic.getYear(),  DPic.getMonth(), DPic.getDayOfMonth(), TPic.getCurrentHour(), TPic.getCurrentMinute());

                Toast.makeText(Display.this, ""+dfDate.format(c.getTime()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                isScheduled=1;
                //------------

                checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();

           for(int i = 0; i < phno1.size(); i++)  //name1

               {
               if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
               {   
                   checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());   //name1
                   checkedcontacts.append(":");
                    checkedcontacts.append(phno1.get(i).toString());   //name1
                    checkedcontacts.append(",");


               }
               else
               {

               }


           }

           Toast.makeText(Display.this, checkedcontacts,1000).show();
            callNumberAndFinish(checkedcontacts);


                //----------
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        ReSet = ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ResetDateTime));
        ReSet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DPic.updateDate(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                TPic.setCurrentHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                TPic.setCurrentMinute(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            }
        });
        Cancel = ((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.CancelDialog));
        Cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });


        ShowDTPicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DPic.updateDate(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                TPic.setCurrentHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                TPic.setCurrentMinute(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                showDialog(DATE_TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
        dialog.setTitle("Select Date Time");
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     ma.toggle(arg2);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    LoginActivity.kill=1;
    Display.this.finish();

  // LActivity.finish();


};
private void callNumberAndFinish(CharSequence number) {
    // if (number == null || number.length() == 0) {
    // Toast.makeText(this, number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // return;
    // }

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        new CallNumber().execute();
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("EezyInvite").setMessage("Invitation Sent Sucessfully.!");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
               dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });     
        final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
        alert.show();

        // Hide after some seconds
        final Handler handler  = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (alert.isShowing()) {
                    alert.dismiss();
                }
            }
        };

        alert.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }
        });

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);

    } else {

        showNoConnectionDialog(Display.this);
    }




}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_TIME_DIALOG_ID:

        return dialog;
    }
    return null;
}
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC" );

    while (phones.moveToNext())
    {
      String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
      String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
     // String id=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
      String uri11=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));
      name1.add(name);
      phno1.add(phoneNumber);
      id1.add(uri11);
    }

   // phones.close();
 }
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
{  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
   LayoutInflater mInflater;
    TextView tv1,tv;
    ImageView img;
    CheckBox cb;
    ArrayList<String> tmpArray;
    ArrayList<String> tmpArray2;
    MyAdapter()
    {
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)Display.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> s,ArrayList<String> s2)
    {   tmpArray=s;
        tmpArray2=s2;
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(s.size());
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)Display.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return tmpArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
         vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null); 
        Drawable background = vi.getBackground();
        background.setAlpha(40);
         tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
         img =(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
         tv.setText(""+ tmpArray.get(position));
         tv1.setText(""+ tmpArray2.get(position));
         if (id1.get(position) != null) {
             img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(id1.get(position)));
         } else {
             img.setImageResource(R.drawable.user);
         }
         //img.setImageURI(id1.get(position));
         cb.setTag(position);
         cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
         cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return vi;
    }
     public boolean isChecked(int position) {
            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
            Log.d("checked contact",""+name1.get(position));
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked); 
         Log.d("checked contact","clicked:::"+buttonView.getTag());
    }   
}   

class CallNumber extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... paramVarArgs) {
        Log.i("  session User Details", "Saving");
        try {  Log.d("checked contacts",""+checkedcontacts.toString());
            String num = checkedcontacts.toString();

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numbers",num));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email_id", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sms", getIntent().getExtras().getString("getsms")));
            Log.d("","scheduled"+isScheduled);
            if(isScheduled==1){
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scheduled_time",dfDate.format(c.getTime())));
                Log.d(" scheduled request!", "starting");
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(SCHEDULE_URL, "GET",params);
                isScheduled=0;
            }else{
            Log.d(" Login request!", "starting");
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(CALL_URL, "GET",params);
             //Log.i("json",""+json.toString());
            }
                //Log.i("json",""+json.toString());

            return null;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            //for (;;) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            //}
        }
        return null;
    }
}
public static void showNoConnectionDialog(Context ctx1) {
    final Context ctx = ctx1;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setMessage("Turn on your internet..!");
    builder.setTitle("No Internet Conncetion");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ctx.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            return;
        }
    });
    builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            return;
        }
    });

    builder.show();

}
}
```

from the above code am able to pick contact from the list using checkboxes, but now i want to add search functionality also . i added edit text and on the text changed am able to get the sorted contacts but previously selected contacts were gone every time. so how to maintain the selected contacts remain selected.

Comment: You are not asking any question. What's your question? If you're thinking "why is it not working?", that's no question either. You have to explain **what exactly** is not working and **how exactly** it's not working (exception, error, ...). Otherwise your question will be closed for being *too broad*.

Comment: i want to implement contact picker. do you have any sample code .

Comment: do u know activityforresult in android

Comment: yes @naveen, i edited my question please help

Comment: Have a look thid code https://github.com/codinguser/android_contact_picker/tree/master/src/com/codinguser/android/contactpicker

Comment: Multipal Contact Picker in Android https://github.com/kgadzinowski/Android-Multiple-Contacts-Picker-Library

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar but this code is only selecting the contacts from the list I want search functionality.

Comment: impliment autocompleteExitText in Above Listview

Comment: yes, I followed this tutorial also i mentioned above but it is not working for me. Am not able to see the contact in the listview, means view is not getting called